# Getting landmarks data contents that are added and deleted between two landmarks layers from shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, layers, date

I have two layers of landmark:

- 2019 version layer(Blue)
- 2020 version layer(Purple)

[image: 2 Thailand landmark layers display]

I want to know landmarks that are added and deleted in year 2020 and I see the landmarks that are added and deleted in year 2020 by order the layers.

[image: Landmark data contents]

How can I get the landmarks data contents that are added and deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple

As you said we have two landmark layers

1. 2019 version layer(Blue)
2. 2020 version layer(Purple)

Please use Selection by location or locational Query

```
Step 1 : Select Feature from Target layer (2020 version layer(Purple)) where source Layer (2019 version layer(Blue)) AND Spatial Selection method for source layer (Such as are identical to source layer feature);

Step 2 : Select Feature from Target layer (2019 version layer(Blue) ) where source Layer (2020 version layer(Purple)) AND Spatial Selection method for source layer (Such as are identical to source layer feature);
```

Note : After selection Please export both results separately.

Step 1 Results will be Newly added points/Landmarks.

Step 2 Results will be Deleted Points/Landmarks.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I use Qgis 3.1.2. At Where the features (geometric predicate) check box selection,there are only intersect,contain,disjoint,equal,touch,overlap,are within and cross.

Comment: In QGIS, Please use the alternative option thank you.